# Round function alternative in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to convert decimal 40.00 to 1 decimal place (40.0)

Round(40.00,2.1)

Can we used any other function.please suggest??

Answer (score 3):

Use Cast as Decimal:

```
select cast(40.00 as decimal(10,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `CAST` or `CONVERT`

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,1), 40.00)
SELECT CAST(40.00 as decimal(10,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast and Decimal function

```
select cast( (40.00 ) as decimal (5,1))
```

Use cast and decimal function